# Struct compiler problems in C

Tags: c++, c

The following can be included from a .cpp file and the compiler won't complain about it.

```
typedef struct _SomeName {
    char NameID[MaxSize];  
    UserId notUsed;
    UserInstance instance;

    bool operator==(const struct _SomeName& rhs) const
    {
        return (strncmp(NameID, rhs.NameID, MaxSize) == 0);
    }
    bool operator!=(const struct _SomeName& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); };
} SomeName;
```

How do I rewrite the above so that it's possible to include it from a .c file ?

Comment: What error are you getting when including it in a .c file?

Comment: C does not support operator overloading, so you cannot port this code without losing functionality.

Comment: c doesn't support operator overloading. so it is not possible.

Comment: Do you mean "how do I compile a .c file as C++" or do you mean "how do I convert the C++ code to C code"?

Comment: @JaviV I would expect something like "unexpected token == on line 6" given that C would try to parse 'operator' as a boolean member variable of the struct.

Comment: You could add `#if 0` to the top and `#endif` to the bottom. That means your stated requirements, but presumably not your actual requirements. Please update your stated requirements.

Comment: As it's a struct and everything is public, you could put the operator outside the struct and maybe in a different header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solutions posted so far have a problem that you cannot use it in a project which mixes C and C++. I am guessing from the context of your question that you might want to do that.  If you try that, you may get silent undefined behaviour because the structure could have a different layout in different translation units.

I'd suggest this version:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char NameID[MaxSize];  
    UserId notUsed;
    UserInstance instance;    
} SomeName;

#ifdef __cplusplus
inline bool operator==( SomeName const &lhs, SomeName const &rhs )
{ 
     return strcmp(lhs.NameID, rhs.NameID) == 0;
}
inline bool operator!=( SomeName const &lhs, SomeName const &rhs )
{
     return !operator==( lhs, rhs );
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that declarations of types `UserId` and `UserInstance` are in scope, you should be able to write this:

```
typedef struct _SomeName {
    char NameID[MaxSize];  
    UserId notUsed;
    UserInstance instance;
#ifdef __cplusplus
    bool operator==(const struct _SomeName& rhs) const
    {
        return (strncmp(NameID, rhs.NameID, MaxSize) == 0);
    }
    bool operator!=(const struct _SomeName& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); };
#endif
} SomeName;
```

Comment: That addresses the assumed constraint that you want to be able to include the same header in C++ sources and C sources, without loss of functionality on the C++ side.  If you don't need the overloaded operators anywhere (for instance, if you need the header only in C) then you could just delete the operator overloads.

Comment: Note that you **must not** have a project where this definition is compiled as C in one place, and as C++ in another place, because this violates the one-definition rule for `SomeName`.  Therefore I would suggest not doing this at all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the exact functionality of the c++ struct, but if you use the `__cplusplus` conditional, you can leave out the parts, the C compiler will not compile.

```
typedef struct _SomeName {
    char NameID[MaxSize];  
    UserId notUsed;
    UserInstance instance;

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    bool operator==(const struct _SomeName& rhs) const
    {
        return (strncmp(NameID, rhs.NameID, MaxSize) == 0);
    }
    bool operator!=(const struct _SomeName& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); };
    #endif
} SomeName;
```

If you need the equal and not equal operator, in both c and c++, I suggest you remove the operator definitions from the struct, and write a pure c interface implementing a `SomeNameEquals` and `SomeNameNotEquals` function.